# Understanding Issues With CSV to Bubble Chart Using D3.js

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

So I've been picking up D3.js to visualize some data I have, and I need a bit of help understanding why certain things happen.

I took the code from [this example on the D3 site](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269), and modified it to read from a flat CSV rather than a flattened JSON file. Here's what it looks like:

```
d3.csv("top-brands.csv", function(csvData) {

  var data = { name: "brand", children: csvData };

  var node = svg.data([data]).selectAll(".node")
        .data(pack.nodes)
      .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })

    node.append("title")
        .text(function(d) { return d.brand; });

    node.append("circle")
        .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
        .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.brand); });

    node.append("text")
        .attr("dy", ".3em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function(d) { return d.brand; });
});
```

It seems to work quite well, in the sense that my bubbles all get drawn with the correct data, but there are two niggling issues that keep coming up:

1. It keeps drawing a large circle that encloses the other circles. It appears to be as large as the canvas allows (480px by 480px) but I have no idea how to make it go away. Is it because of how my data is processed?
2. If I try to do anything with "d.brand" in any way, it will tell me that d.brand is undefined. The example from the D3 site takes the title and gets the substring if the length is too long, but I can't seem to do that. Is it because of the way I'm pulling my data?

Appreciate any help! I can't really provide example CSVs because it's proprietary data, but it's just three columns: brand, count, and proportion, which is a string, an int, and a float (percentage) in that order. Dummy data would work just fine, I think.

Thanks SO!

Comment: Keep in mind that the pack layout creates nodes for everything — not only the children (i.e. leaf nodes) that come from your CSV, but also including the root node, which you're creating as `{ name: "brand", children: csvData }`. This is what causes the large circle to appear. And, this node also doesn't have a brand property. So when a function is passed `d`, this `d` could be the parent node, in which case you need to treat it differently (like hide it or not label it). You can detect whether a node is parent or not by checking its `depth` property (I think).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @meetamit! I'm not entirely sure how I would exclude the first iteration or the parent node from being included. Perhaps I'm just too inexperienced with this, but any sort of change I make apparently breaks the whole thing, so I'm just tinkering now...